# How to declare parameters in C

Tags: c, variables, parameters

I have a bunch of parameters (integers and floats); I want to write a C code where both the main program and the functions refer to the same parameters so that if I change one of them the whole code knows the new value I set. My code is formed by a main.c file which calls a function.c file; right now I declared the parameters both in the main and in the function but I think that is not robust (if I change one parameters in the main and I forget to change it also in the function I get wrong results). So here is the question: How can declare the parameters in order to change it just once and not to change it everywhere I have defined?

PS: i don't want to use `#define` because it doesn't allow me to specify whether it's an integer or not.

Comment: Something wrong with `const`?

Comment: Sounds like you're asking how to define global variables. Just define variables outside any function, and use them wherever. Warning: global variables can (and often do) lead to subtle interactions and dependencies between different parts of the code, so you generally want to minimize their use, and generally avoid them as much as possible.

Comment: So why `#define` is not good for you? Can you show an example?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a global variable, define it at the top of the main.c file and refer it at the top of the other .c file using the declaration "extern".
main.c
@include
...
int a;//global variable

function.c

## include ...

extern int a;//global variable

Answer (score 0):

You can use global variables.

1. Create a .h files -- let's call it `globals.h`. Put declarations of the global variables in the file.

   ```
   extern int var1;
   extern float var2;
   extern double var3;
   ```
2. Create a .c file -- let's call it `globals.c`. Define the variables in the file.

   ```
   #include "globals.h"

   int var1 = 0;
   float var2 = 10.0f;
   double var3 = 200.0;
   ```
3. Use `#include "globals.h"` in any .c file in which you want to access the global variable.

   ```
   #include "globals.h"

   int main()
   {
       printf("var1 : %d\n", var1);
       printf("var2 : %f\n", var2);
       printf("var3 : %lf\n", var3);
   }
   ```

If you change the values of `var1`, `var2`, or `var3` anywhere in the program, the change will take effect for all the functions that access them.

Answer (score 0):

You could use static consts, to all intents and purposes your effect will be achieved.

```
myext.h:
#ifndef _MYEXT_H
#define _MYEXT_H
static const int myx = 245;
static const unsigned long int myy = 45678;
static const double myz = 3.14;
#endif

myfunc.h:
#ifndef MYFUNC_H
#define MYFUNC_H
void myfunc(void);
#endif

myfunc.c:
#include "myext.h"
#include "myfunc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

void myfunc(void)
{
    printf("%d\t%lu\t%f\n", myx, myy, myz);
}

myext.c:
#include "myext.h"
#include "myfunc.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    printf("%d\t%lu\t%f\n", myx, myy, myz);
    myfunc();
    return 0;
}
```